# if for a Matrix A $ A^3 = 0 $ and A has an Inverse is it safe to assume that A = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question. I searched and haven't found anyone has asked it before (probably because it's so obvious).

I went over some basic exercises and found one that asks me to find an example where $A$ does not equal $0$ and $A^3 = 0$. There are plenty of example Matrices. But on the other hand, I thought isn't $ A^3 $ just $ AAA $ ? And then if I have $AAA = 0$ and continuously multiply by An inverse on the left or right twice I get $A=0$.

I find this intuitive and though it looks obvious, often my intuition has deceived me. I'd be grateful if someone can confirm if right or explain to me if wrong why I can't multiply by $A$ inverse.

Octave gives me a pseudoinverse for $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: if you multiply $A$ by its pseudoinverse, it does not vanish, since in general $A^\dagger A\ne I$

Comment: $A$ is not invertible since $A^3=0\implies|A^3|=|A|^3=0\implies|A|=0$

Comment: When you know, that $A$ has an inverse, $A$ can not be zero! $0$ does not have an inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A^3 = 0$, then $A$ doesn't have an inverse! For: if $A$ had an inverse, then you could calculate
$$
\left(A^{-1}\right)^3 A^3 = A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}AAA = A^{-1}A^{-1}AA = A^{-1}A = I.
$$
Yet also,
$$
\left(A^{-1}\right)^3 A^3 = \left(A^{-1}\right)^3 0 = 0.
$$
But $I \neq 0$, so $A$ does not have an inverse at all.

Comment: Oh right. I think. So if A had an inverse I could for $A = 0 $ do $ A^(-1)A=0=I$ ? is that correct?

Comment: If $A = 0$ then $A$ doesn't have an inverse, so I guess what you wrote is *technically* correct but doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I can see now why it doesn't have an inverse too thanks to your example

Comment: To be extremely pedantic, the only case in which $A$ could be invertible and nilpotent at the same time is when it is square of order $0$, in other words belonging to the ring $\mathscr{M}_0(A)$ of matrices with $0$ rows and $0$ columns over the given ring of scalars $A$.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ thank you, I've recently went into studying rings and this is a cool thing to point out. Would some people call this trivial though?

Comment: @oliver Anyone would call it trivial, for it is indeed a trivial ring (i.e. a ring having only one element, or equivalently one in which the zero and the unity coincide). They are rather uninteresting nevertheless they do exist.

Answer (score 1):

$\det({A^3})=\left(\det A\right)^3=0$, so $\det(A)=0$ and $A$ has no inverse.

Comment: Thank you, this is also a very good and intuitive way to think about it.